# Помогите до решать простую задачу

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Задание: Дана матрица (размером 3 на 3). Вывести на экран все нечетные строки. Задание выполнить нужно на C++ в Visual studio 2019. Вот мой код:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    srand(unsigned(time(0)));
    int a[3][3] = {};
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = rand() % 100;
            cout << a[i][j] << "";

        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            cout << a[i][j] << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Просьба: я не понимаю как дальше написать программу, а именно как сделать ввод матрицы и вывод только нечетных строк буду очень благодарен за помощь...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто и топорно: проверять номер строки. Если нечетный - выводить. Если четный - не выводить.

А если подумать и применить знания:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
             ^---------^-------здесь может быть не  только 0, но и, например, 1
                       '---------- а здесь может быть не только i++, но и например, i = i+2
```